# Access iframe elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a webpage where there is a textarea within an iframe. I need to read the value of this textarea from its child page using JavaScript.

Presently by using `window.parent.getelementbyID().value` in the JavaScript, I am able to fetch values of all controls in the parent page except the textarea within the iframe.

Can anyone please give me any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can anyone help me please with the logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access iFrame elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: Use `window.frames['myIFrame'].contentDocument.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')` which works in modern browsers (e.g. Firefox 35) -- and pay attention to the same-origin policy

Comment: @CAW is absolutely right its working now

Comment: Consider to use cross-document messaging.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If your iframe is in the same domain as your parent page you can access the elements using `window.frames` collection.

```
// replace myIFrame with your iFrame id
// replace myIFrameElemId with your iFrame's element id
// you can work on window.frames['myIFrame'].document like you are working on
// normal document object in JS
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

If your iframe is not in the same domain the browser should prevent such access for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions.
But the problem is that the frame id n frame name in my parent page changes in runtime, hence we cannot use the frame id/frame name for reference.
Is there any other way Ra Yell?..

Comment: Bith parent n child page are in same domain.

Comment: If there is ony one iframe on your site you could try using `document,frames[0].document`. If there are more you need to change the index to some other value.

Comment: `document.frames` no longer works. Use `window.frames` instead.

Comment: To confirm what @tylerl said, I just checked in Firefox 25 and Chrome 31. In both cases `document.frames` was undefined, but `window.frames` worked perfectly

Comment: Wow, didn't realize I downvoted this instead of upvoting. And now it's too late to undo. Apologies!

Comment: `.contentDocument` rather than `document` works for me

Answer (score 17):

`window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')`

not working for me but I found another solution. Use:

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].contentDocument.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

I checked it on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I keep hitting a security error even though the web pages are both offline.

Comment: dont look anything else this is the actual answer, superb

Answer (score 15):

You should access frames from `window` and not `document`

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your iframe **is already loaded**. Old but reliable way without jQuery:

```
<iframe src="samedomain.com/page.htm" id="iframe" onload="access()"></iframe>

<script>
function access() {
   var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
   var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
   console.log(innerDoc.body);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Two ways**

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].contentDocument.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

OR

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].contentWindow.document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

Answer (score 2):

this code worked for me:

```js
window.frames['myIFrame'].contentDocument.getElementById('myIFrameElemId');
```