# How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a webpage where there is a textarea within a iframe. I need to read the value of this textarea from its child page JavaScript. Presently by using `window.parent.getelementbyID().value` in the JavaScript, I am able to fetch values of all controls in the parent page except the textarea within the iframe.

The frame id and frame name in my parent page changes in runtime, hence we cannot use the frame id/frame name for reference.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208

Comment: @archana: RaYell's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/1451455#1451455 includes a comment from the first time you asked this question. If you do not know the frame id or name, you can use `document.frames[0].document.getElementById()` (or some other index if it is not the first `<iframe>` on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access iframe elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you have the HTML

```
<form name="formname" .... id="form-first">
    <iframe id="one" src="iframe2.html">
    </iframe>
</form>
```

and JavaScript

```
function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
    return frameRef.contentWindow
        ? frameRef.contentWindow.document
        : frameRef.contentDocument
}

var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('one') )
```

`inside` is now a reference to the document, so you can do `getElementsByTagName('textarea')` and whatever you like, depending on what's inside the iframe src.

Comment: Just 1 concern Meder--
var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('one') )

The frameid n framename in my page changes in runtime, so it wont be possible to pass the frameid(as done by you).
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: yes. getElementsByTagName('iframe') to refer to a nodeList and access elements inside with [0], assuming you're dealing with one. or you can do a loop.

Comment: Thanks Meder. Just 1 more query--
Whats the difference between--
'frameRef.contentWindow.document' and 'frameRef.contentDocument'

I want to understand the concept behind this.
It would be really good of you,if you explain it a bit.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: An explanation can be found @ http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/
Some browsers support one of those dom properties, and I just check for either.

Comment: You r a genius Meder.
Thanks a ton for your instant help.

Answer (score 19):

Using jQuery you can use `contents()`. For example:

```
var inside = $('#one').contents();
```

Comment: An important consideration here is that the contents method can "get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page."