# Control a text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to disable a control on a page using javascript.. I am doing the following but not able to do it successfully.. anything I am missing, please point out..

```
       if (some condition) {        
        var textBoxTemp = document.getElementById('_ctl21_m_txtTemp');
        textBoxTemp.disabled = true;
        }
```

I got the element id by looking at the source of the page. In the source the id shows

> _ctl21:m_txtTemp

I tried using both

> _ctl21:m_txtTemp and _ctl21_m_txtTemp

in the second line of code above..

Comment: Are you sure that testBoxTemp exists? sounds like you're using ASP controls - view-source the page and double check the element's id

Comment: yes its _ctl21_m_txtTemp

Comment: can you show the aspx page markup related to txtTemp?

Comment: <td style="height: 19px">
                        <input name="_ctl21:m_m_txtTemp" type="text" id="_ctl21_m_m_txtTemp" class="inputNormalRequired" style="width: 32px;" size="1" value="100" />
                      </td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to disable the textbox.

```
$("[id$=txtTemp]").prop("disabled", true);
```

Note: prop() is only available after jquery 1.6. If you are using an earlier version, you can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead:

```
$("[id$=txtTemp]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

**Edit**:

Since ASP.NET tends to mangle the ID of a control, there are several different ways you can find the control on the page such as:

```
$('[id$=txtTemp]')
$('#<%= txtTemp.ClientID %>')
```

**Edit**:

Since you seem to think that your control could be in an iframe, I found this solution from the following stackoverflow question: [how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

```
function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
    return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
}

var iframe = iframeRef( document.getElementById('iframeID') )
```

You will now be able to search the iframe content as if it was the document via:

```
iframe.getElementByID('<%= txtTemp.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
```

Comment: tried all these ideas.. it does not seem to work.. I am suspecting the problem lies somewhere else.. if the field is in a frame inside the page, how do I get hold of the id and disable it in that case..because right now, no matter what I try, jqyer, javascript and so many of these possible solutions..it does not disable the control at all..

Comment: Just so I am understanding, you have a page that has an iframe, and you are trying to disable a textbox within the iframe from the parent page.?

Comment: I dont know that.. its in a frame.. or not.. this should be simple to fix and no matter what I try its not working.. makes me think that the control is not straightforward on the page.. may be its not finding the id if I do it this way..

Comment: I think we need to see more of your html to really be able to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11398/discussion-between-zvenue-and-josh-mein)

Comment: I am sorry.. I cant seem to connect to chat due to browser policy here.. you gmail? my id is ezboy4@gmail.com.. there is gmail chat.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Jquery, so I suppose I can provide a jquery solution:

```
if (some_condition)
{
  $('#_ctl21_m_txtTemp').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Comment: I tried this.. but does not work for me.. a alert before the jquery line works showing me its getting into the if statement. but the jquery line does not work..

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery you can do

`$('#<%= txtTemp.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");`

This ensures you get the right client id in case you move the textbox around.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, I wouldn't use document.getElementById, that totally not the point

```
textBoxTemp = $('#_ctl21_m_txtTemp'); // weird name, by the way
textBoxTemp.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: it's the generated name since it's a server control

Answer (score 0):

according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

the syntax should be

```
textBoxTemp.disabled="disabled"
```

you could give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're wanting this in jQuery or plain old Javascript, but here it is in both:

**Javascript**

(you're probably looking for the readonly attribute instead of disabled)

```
var textBoxTemp = document.getElementById('_ctl21_m_txtTemp');
textBoxTemp.readonly = true;
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#_ctl21_m_txtTemp').attr('readonly',true);
```

Comment: tried both.. it does not seem to work.. I am suspecting the problem lies somewhere else.. if the field is in a frame inside the page, how do I get hold of the id and disable it in that case..because right now, no matter what I try, jqyer, javascript and so many of these possible solutions..it does not disable the control at all..