# Trigger form submission in chrome javascript console

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, submit

Just a little thing I've always wondered:

Is it possible to submit a form on any webpage, rather than clicking the forms submit button, I want to do it from the chrome console (ctrl+shift+j in chrome)?

I've tried a couple ways but I either get an error like

> Cannot use function submit on undefined

or

> HTML tag has not function submit.

Any help?

PS - If you go here and try and submit the form on your right through the console [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit)

Comment: What have you entered in the console? On which page did you do that?

Answer (score 12):

```
form = document.getElementById("frm1")
form.submit()
```

works on your example when viewing the standalone [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit_view.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit).

Answer (score 0):

For your example when working with an iframe:

```
 // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript
 function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
     return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
 }

 var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0] );


 // from @DeanGrobier
 form = inside.getElementById("frm1")

 form.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inside an iframe in your example. In your case, you must enter this in the console for it to work:

```
var q = window.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1];
var r = q.contentWindow.document.getElementById("frm1");
r.submit();
```

or, in just one line:

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentWindow.document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
```