# javascript load external content in div

Tags: javascript, load, external

I'd like to find the **best** solution for loading external content (from php script, external website) in a div with javascript code (no jQuery, Mootools or any other lib, just pure JS). It must work in any browser, even IE :) What is the best way to achieve this?

I found lots of posts about this, but a lot of them where old, or with no certain solution. Or is it better to achieve this with *iframe*?

Comment: If you want a good cross-browser solution, and you don't want to use jQuery or some other framework, you're making it very hard for yourself.

Comment: You can try use native XMLHttpRequest. Here are some tutorials on how make ajax call with native object: http://www.cristiandarie.ro/asp-ajax/Async.html, http://blog.sociomantic.com/2010/08/native-javascript-ninjutsu-ajax-with-xhr/

Comment: Yes I know, but there is no way I can use any framework. It needs to work on every website even without frameworks. It based on the idea that user copy/paste the code into his website and after every load website loads content from external source.

Comment: OK, XMLHttpRequest is fine, but how to handle IE browsers with ActiveX turned off?

Comment: @MartinMalych - IE7 and above uses a native XMLHttpRequest object, so you don't need ActiveX enabled.

Comment: helpful link for u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript