# Dynamic DOM elements not accessible?

Tags: javascript

I can see a DOM element with an ID of Foo by using the debug inspector.

This DOM element is inserted dynamically by a script that I do not have access to.

Because of this you can not see it when you do View->Source.

When I try to access the element using

`document.getElementById('Foo')`, it returns a null b.c. it can not find it.

Verified this in the debug console as well.

Is it possible to get elements that are inserted dynamically?

I ask b.c. I would like to remove the node.

Comment: Maybe you try to access the element before its created.

Comment: no I used the console debugger after the page was completely loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
function addElement() {
    var foo = document.createElement('p');
    foo.id = "bar";
    document.body.appendChild(foo);
}
function getElement() {
    alert(document.getElementById('bar'));
}    

addElement();
getElement();
```

See also [a live demo of this](http://jsfiddle.net/KvsEP/).

Why your example doesn't work is hard to say as  you haven't provided any details.

At a guess, the element you are seeing is in a different document, embedded in an iframe, in which case you would have to [access the document in the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript) before calling `getElementById` on it. This is, of course, subject to [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
    ​

Comment: As I suggested was likely, it is in a different document in an iframe. That iframe is on a different origin, so you can't (and since the advert is the "payment" they take for providing the service, you shouldn't even if you could).

Comment: Most DOM inspectors will show nested documents in iframes as part of the DOM. They are still different documents.

Comment: I looked at it in a DOM inspector. https://skitch.com/dorward/esqap/nested-document

Comment: I guess everything in that iFrame is read only and protected by the Browser?

Comment: As I said in the answer, it is protected by the same origin policy. So most of it is inaccessible (not read only, completely inaccessible). A few parts will be write only. (Those parts do not include any of the element nodes as they all descend form things that cannot be read).

Comment: that is neat...it's like they own part of the web application.

Comment: You have a script element with the src pointing to a URL on their server in your page. They *do* own part of the web application.