# How to update form in an iFrame from input field in the main document?

Tags: iframe, submit, program-entry-point

I have a text input field (email address) with a submit button in the main document and a form in an iFrame. When I click on the submit button in the main document, the email address in the form in the iFrame should be updated with the value entered into the text input field in the main document. How to do that exactly? :S

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected my answer. You can find more info here perhaps: [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Keep in mind that you have a cross-domain restrictions in most browsers, that will not allow you to tamper with an iframe that is on another domain comparing to your "main document".