# links within an iframe window to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen this question many times, and a lot of the answers seem to suggest the base `target="_blank"` technique. However, I have used this before in the past; but my current page it does not work. I also don't think it could be best option even if it did work; as I ONLY want the links within the `iframe src=""` to open in a new window. I am hopping there's a simple solution I can add inline to the page. I have also tried adding an id as below, and using JavaScript, still nada.

```
<iframe src="mywordpressfeed.html" id="frame1" width="310" height="380"></iframe>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frame1").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Basically the goal is to when a user sees my wordpress feed within the iframe I have on a static page; once the post title is clicked it loads in a new window - as now it loads within the same iframe so there isn't an increased level of readability.

Comment: `"target"` is an attribute of the anchor tag, not the iframe tag.

Comment: Can you not edit your Wordpress theme/code/feed to give hyperlinks the target="_blank" option?

Comment: Thanks for the response @adaam but no, because when users are there I don't want it to be a new page per post click. Only on the splash homepage where I have the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real solution to this, due to the iFrame tag being developed for the opposite.

Comment: What does "...the iFrame tag being developed for the opposite." mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
//pass the iframe to this iframe getting function 
    function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
        return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
    }
//Get Iframe
    var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('iframeID') );
//Get all links
    var links = inside.getElementsByTagName('a');
//Loop throught links and set their attributes
    for (var i = 0 ; i<links.length ; i++){
    links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }
//No jQuery needed!
```

thanks to [meder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

**EDIT**
Due to iframe same source restrictions I had to find a website with inner iframe from same source so you can paste this code

```
//pass the iframe to this iframe getting function 
    function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
        return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
    }
//Get Iframe
    var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('IFwinEdit_Gadget_247730_3349') );
//Get all links
    var links = inside.getElementsByTagName('input');
//Loop throught links and set their attributes
    for (var i = 0 ; i<links.length ; i++){
        links[i].setAttribute('style','background:red');
    }
//No jQuery needed!
```

to the console in this [web site](http://www.oferanaby.co.il/212028/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9F) and see the inputs change color

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing @raam86 but still no such luck =/

Comment: Anything else I should be including here? Cheers.

Comment: post some HTML for more assitance also paste the console error

Comment: Thanks a ton again, @raam86 you are the man. The only relevant HTML is the iframe markup in the original post. I am however getting a console error with both codes stating "error: document.getElementById(...)" is null.

Comment: are you using frame1 as frameref? also notoce crosd web site restrictions

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling there is no real solution to this.