# How to make all links in an iframe open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to make it so when you click on a link in an `<iframe>` it will open the link in a new tab - not in the `<iframe>`.   Please note I do not have control of the content the people are viewing through the `<iframe>`.

I'm trying to do this with javascript possibly, like `$('a').setAttribute('target','_blank');`
but it's not working out for me.
I also have in my HTML document `<base target="_blank">`, that is not doing the trick too.

Is this impossible?  Or am I just searching in the wrong places? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is iframe page is from same domain??

Comment: try parent.window.open("{{your location}}");

Comment: similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128889/links-within-an-iframe-window-to-open-in-new-tab?rq=1

Comment: There might be similar questions, but they have specs.  And the iframe is on my webpage, the content the iframe is displaying is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd expect this :

```
$('a').setAttribute('target','_blank');
```

.. to fail (silently - because jquery generally fails silently) because, if the content of the iFrame is from a different Domain, there are access issues with manipulating the page within the iFrame from the containing page.

That is : If your own page is from domain a (eg mysite.com), and the iframe is from domain b (eg someothersite.com), then web browser security behaviour is such that using javascript to manipulate the iFrame content will give an "Access is denied" error.

If you were to use non-jquery javascript you'll see the error. From the parent page, something likie this :

```
window.frames["iFrameName"].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].target="_blank"
```

you'll see the error.

Unfortunately I'm not sure what you can do about this. It's a deliberate thing to stop one website including another, and changing the content after loading so that it says something else.

One way around it would be to call a script on your server (ie same domain) and pass in a URL. The script gets the content of the page you were after and regurgitates it to your browser, so you'll have the content of your desired webpage but the address of it was within your site.. eg if it were php:

http://yourdomain.com/getURL.php?url=http:www.google.com

Watch out for issues with authentication there though

Answer (score 33):

To load all links on the page in the parent window use:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

else in a new window use:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

Answer (score 3):

check this solution it helped me: [Make links inside an iframe open in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583792/make-links-inside-an-iframe-open-in-a-new-window)

or you can try this code: `parent.window.open("{{your location}}");`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `target='blank'` with `onclick='window.open();'`

Comment: Lol, that's the only thing that actually worked from all other solutions I have tried. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

using javascript

```
var links= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
   links[i].setAttribute('target', '_top');
}
```

using jquery

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if (!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).attr("target","_top");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('a').attr('target','_blank');` instead of setAttribute...

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/3n5kF/)**

Comment: You are just telling him to use different JavaScript notation. How does this solve the question at all? This would be better served as a comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: I upvoted because it does fix the proposed JS. OP had two problems.