# Open iframe PDF links in new tab (Chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I have a PDF in an iframe, for example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf"></iframe>
```

In Chrome (at least), clicking the link in the bottom left corner of the PDF causes the parent (containing) frame to navigate to http://www.irs.gov/form1040.

Is there way to make this link to open in a new tab instead?

Comment: Might be useful to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808065/how-to-make-all-links-in-an-iframe-open-in-new-tab