# unable to access child iframe DOM from parent webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, cross-domain

I was assigned a task to open a web page in iframe and user can navigate to inner pages in the iframe. But my task is to get the URL of inner page of iframe using Javascript or Jquery.

Let me explain the issue clearly,
I have a Webpage (say abc.corp.com) and I'm displaying one more webpage (say bcd.corp.com) using iframe. Basically both are from "corp.com" but I'm unable to access the child iframe DOM, we are getting permission denied access while trying to access the iframe object.

The child iframe page (bcd.corp.com) is developed and maintained by other team and we don't have access to the webpage.

We tried to change the document.domain property of both parent page and child iframe page to same domain "corp.com" but we cant modify the child iframe page domain.

Please provide a workaround for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

"unable to access child iframe DOM from parent webpage"

I think that's one goal of an iframe, to separate the DOM's. But, you can get access with something like this.

```
function getIFrameDom( referenceToYourIFrame ) {
     return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document :  frameRef.contentDocument
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried both contentWindow and contectDocument. unable to access it. Any other suggestions ??