# Hide another page's button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to load another site's page (e.g: www.a.com/b.html) on my site's page. TO do that I use an iframe to do that. But in that page (b.html), there is a button that I need to hide. Is there any way to hide that button with javascript or jquery.

Is there any other way to get the content of that page and edit some and display on my page.

Comment: yes use large Z index to put a div to make that happen.

Comment: Also, check this "stackoveflow" question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

$().contents should allow you to access the elements within an iFrame

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#btnId');
```