# Change the content or draw in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I've got a series of X and Y coordinates and I want to use these coordinates with `<canvas>` to basically draw small rectangles on the iframe wherever these coordinates happen to be.  Is there a way I can edit the inner HTML code of an iframe or be able to draw on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the iframe contents using javascript as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript).
This has nothing to do with php.