# How get the map variable from a parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, qgis

I have a leaflet map, exported from QGIS. I don't want to modify the code inside that exported folder.

I successfully embedded the map inside another page, using a `<iframe>` tag.

Now, I want, in the javascript code of my parent page, get the map variable so I cant tweak its parameters (position, bounds, etc...)

**How can I get this map variable in my parent page javascript ?**

**parent**

```
 <iframe id = 'iframeid'
   src="/qgis/index.html"
   scrolling="no"
   frameborder="0"
   style="height: 100vh;
   width: 100%">
 </iframe>
 <script>
 var map = ????
 </script>
```

**child** (qgis-exported leaflet map)

```
<script>
  var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl:true, maxZoom:20, minZoom:15});

  /* I need te following lines inside the parent file. */
  var lat = -0.017;
  var lng = 0.015;
  var zoom = 16;
  map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: The map is a js variable, can the question you linked solve also when working with a js variable ?

Comment: javascript as opposed to what? js is the only scripting language you can use in a browser, so yea. everything is javascript. there are no other options.

Comment: I meant that I was not sure that the method for getting an element with its id works with js variables. All those examples are for getting an element it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If `map` is the global variable referencing the Leaflet map in your `iframe`, then in the parent page, do

```
var map = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.map // supposing you only have one iframe, else select it by its id or something like this
```

to access it.

Note that it will only work if both `iframe` and `parent` share same **domain**, **protocol** and **host**.