# How to change width/height of iframe with document.getElementByid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I tried using `document.getElementById("frame-id")`, but it seems buggy. Mostly it returns `undefined` or `null` but sometimes it returns the iframe only for the first time it is called then again it starts returning `undefined`. Also I am unable to change or get style properties with `document.getElementById("frame-id").style.width`. E.g. here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lfq2u2o1/1/ You can check with the console.

Why are iframe elements not accesible with `document.getElementByid` or `document.getElementsByClassName` in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: In the code you posted there isn't inside the iframe tag the id="frame-id"

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript code is executed after the iframe html tag is declared in the DOM?

Comment: @Pierfrancesco I am using javascript only in the console window after some time the page loads completely.

Comment: "You can check with the console" — Not when it is JS Fiddle, since the frame containing your document isn't the top level frame so `document` will be the wrong document.

Comment: @Quentin It also doesn't work in the html file opened directly in web browser.

Comment: @user31782 — It does here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPNApWNCodE37RNcb1YHo2WcFBb5g2TvtU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are. You can't do anything *inside* the iframe with javascript (with the exception of window.postMessage()) but element selection works like any other selector in javascript.

Adding

```
console.log(document.getElementById("frame-id"));
```

to your fiddle should work perfectly.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById("frame-id"));` returns undefined.

Comment: Are you running this on your site or in the snippet?

Comment: I tried both. I used everything inside the html file and console window both.

Comment: Nothing happens on this jsfiddle too.

Comment: Note that you can't run javascript in the console on a jsfiddle. The jsfiddle content gets put into an iframe and you'll run into security constrictions.

Comment: Here, since alerts are easier to verify than something in the console, what do you see on this one? https://jsfiddle.net/Lfq2u2o1/3/

Comment: Yes it is working now. But then why does document.getElementById("frame-id") return _undefined_ or _null_ after second call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111858/discussion-between-michael-ambrose-and-user31782).

Comment: Can I change height of iframe with `document.getElementsByClassName("main-video")[0].getAttribute("height")`?

Comment: Yes, use something like this: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('main-video')[0].style.width = '200px')`

Comment: Actually I want to do the following, but it is not working: `var framewidth = document.getElementsByClassName("main-video")[0].getAttribute("width");
 document.getElementsByClassName("main-video")[0].getAttribute("height") = 9/16 * framewidth;`

Comment: To get existing styles that aren't explicitly set on an element (such as in a class, etc) use `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('main-video')[0]).height`

Comment: I've explicitly set them on them live site. `document.getElementsByClassName('main-video')[0].style.width = '200px'` doesn't work. Although `document.getElementsByClassName("main-video")[0].getAttribute("height")` works but it is not changable.

Comment: getAttribute is only for *getting* attributes, not setting. Try this: `var framewidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('main-video')[0]).width); document.getElementsByClassName("main-video")[0].style.height = (9/16 * framewidth) + 'px';` It requires no css styling whatsoever.