# How to access data within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, iframe

I have been trying to access data from an iframe. I am working on codeigniter. I have spent my whole day searching for the solution, but no luck. I am not an expert in javascript, so it is becoming more difficult to me. Please have a look at my code.

`home-upload-dialog.php` view file

```
<div id="popup-contents">
    <iframe id="upload-frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="200" width="100%" src="<?php echo site_url('home/upload_area/' . $_REQUEST['count']);?>"></iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="run()">
<script>
    run() {
        var iframedoc = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
        var inputs = iframedoc.getElementById('text');
        console.log(inputs);
    }
</script>
```

`home.php` controller

```
upload_area() {
    $data['count'] = $count;
    $this->load->view('upload-area', $data);
}
```

`upload-area.php` view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="someValue">
    </body>
    </html>
```

I get the error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined`
There might be things I overlooked. Any help would be appreciated !

I also tried `$('iframe').contents().find('#text').html();` but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: I already visited that page and still have the same problem.

Comment: Just a tip, I tried to fix an issue with a webinterface (which uses frames) a few days ago, I used `window.frames['name_of_the_frame'].document`

Comment: It still says `cannot read property 'document' of undefined`
There might be small silly mistakes in my codes. But I have tried many options with no result.

Comment: Your `iframe` needs to have a `name` attribute.

Comment: I already did that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already many answers to your questions, google "access DOM inside iframe" for several solutions, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript).

In general remember that you **cannot** access the iframe data if the iframe is loaded on another domain for security reasons (otherwise imagine the "Like" widget from Facebook, you could load it and then steal the authorization cookie of the users visiting your website...)

**EDIT**: Note that the security limitation above includes funny situations like your website is loaded from "www.domain.com/page.php" and your iframe from "domain.com/iframe.php", so check that out.

Comment: Instead of making an answer pointing to a question answering the exact same question, flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for the tip, I'm new here :)

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by another domain ?

Comment: Use "View source" on the page loading the iframe, and compare the <iframe src="..."> part with the URL on top of your browser.

Comment: Ohh okay. So it's in the same domain and I'm still getting the error. Any solutions ?