# how to post to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

ive been searching but nothing seems to fit with my situation.

i have a form for adding person data. within the form i have an iframe which is also a form for adding relatives data. i need the personID to have like the fkey for the relative.

i dont know how to access the personID. how can i do this? i want to use jquery or ajax

```
<iframe height="400px" width="100%" src="relativeForm.php" name="iframe_relativeForm" id="iframe_relativeForm"></iframe>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

1. you simply have to post to your relativeForm.php
2. please don't use iframes. you will get problems with ios because they don't manage iframes