# javascript change font in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

im trying to change the font in iframe , but uts not working , now i have used 2 different functions but none of them worked ...

first i have used the following script below to make sure this is the iframe i want to change its font :

```
var X1 = document.getElementById("if1").contentWindow.frames[1].location.href;
alert (X1);
```

then i wrote theses 2 functions and none of then did the job :

method 1 :

```
function changeSize() {
    var frame = document.getElementById("if1");
    var content = (frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow);
    content.body.style.fontSize = "200%";
}
```

method 2 :

```
function changeSize() {

       var r =  document.getElementById("if1").contentWindow.frames[1].querySelector('body');



          r.style.fontSize = '200%';
}
```

both didnt work with me , any help where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript), they access their iFrame via javascript and describe how to edit the ref. Should get you going.