# Can I edit styles of an HTML page which has shown as an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an iframe in my website. It shows an article. And I need to make a button to increase the font size of that HTML page. Button must be in the parent page. Is it possible ? And how ?

Comment: If you control iframe page code you can. Otherwise no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Also:

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php

You can access the `iframe` DOM element from JavaScript and check it for

`ifrm.contentDocument` or

`ifrm.contentWindow.document` properties.

```
// reference to iframe with id 'ifrm'
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm');

// using reference to iframe (ifrm) obtained above
var win = ifrm.contentWindow; // reference to iframe's window
// reference to document in iframe
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
// reference to form named 'demoForm' in iframe
var form = doc.getElementById('demoForm');
```