# How do I populate on page load, login details into a form embedded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

The url is http://gps.itrace.co.za/
I'm going to embed it as an iframe into another site, and I need username: "demo" password "demo" for example, to appear in the form fields as soon as the page loads. the iframe is giving me a headache. Any idea?

Comment: um, do you control that page in the iframe? What have you tried that does not work?

Comment: You need to have access to the code on that iframe because whatever code you end up with will be reading that particular page's code, and in that all you have is `<iframe>` and the `URL` not the elements you are trying to fill in the iframe. So you can't select those particular classes or id's.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452885/7885142