# Cant delete elements inside a iframe with javascript written in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Trying to delete 3 elements that are inside an iframe. Function "Delete" responsible for deleting the elements called on the element body onload doesn't run.

```
 <html>
    <script>
        <?php 
    echo"function delete(){ 
    var elem0=document.getElementById('".$_GET['id']."').contentWindow.document.getElementById('".$id."');
    var elem1=document.getElementById('".$_GET['id']."').contentWindow.document.getElementById('".$id1."');
    var elem2=document.getElementById('".$_GET['id']."').contentWindow.document.getElementById('".$id2."');

    elem0.removeChild(elem0.childNodes[0]);
    elem1.removeChild(elem1.childNodes[0]);
    elem2.removeChild(elem2.childNodes[0]);
    }"; ?>
    </script> 

    <body onload="delete();">
        <div>
        <?php

    $page=$_GET['id'].".html";
    $id=down;
    $id1=gerar1;
    $id2=gerar; 

              echo '<iframe src="' .$page.'" id="'.$_GET['id'].'" frameBorder="0" width="70%" height="100%" align="left" scrolling="no" />';
              echo '</iframe>';
        ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php
    echo'<iframe src="../../galeria/frame2_galeria.html" frameBorder="0" width="29%" height="600px" align="right" scrolling="yes" />    
    </iframe>';
        ?>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Is this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript

Comment: add `bracket ()` after function name `function delete()`

Comment: @Terry Wei my problem is calling the function because when I run in the console "getElement" i can access it.

Comment: If that's going to work all, it'll only work if you move the deletion into the iframe's onload.

Comment: @Dr.Strange i added the bracket and it dind't work either

Comment: can you show us the generated html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete()` is a keyword thats why your function was not call

Use different function name instead of `delete`

So its Works ...!

Comment: Just one more thing, when i delete the element the css applied to the element stays in the page, how do i delete it? Bc the function applied to the button stays.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the iframe is not loaded done.

You just need to add the onload event handler to the iframe or something like setTimeout and put delete into it:

```
iframe.onload = function() { delete(); };
```

that should work.