# Access document inside iframe webscraping

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am **scraping** a webpage I am unable to access the element inside the iframe as I don't know how to access the element #document It is not a element so I can't access it
what is the proper way to do it

[image: The #document has the content that i want to access]

URL for the site whose content i want to get

https://srnovelas.com/rubi-2004-capitulo-1/

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to get the src of videos from the iframe but currently it is hidden by a map url if that is the thing
if i try to access that url it shows me message that i cant access it so
after clicking on play button the video appears and new html is available then If we right click on the video then we get dailog which says that we can copy the link
As I have no control over the backend and its just a random site how am i supposed to get that url that is actually video
Such that user gives any url of this site with episode number e.g.

```
*https://srnovelas.com/rubi-2004-capitulo-1/*
*https://srnovelas.com/rubi-2004-capitulo-2/*
```

and so on
will return me the actual episode url

Comment: Here's what you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)