# How do I let one iframe's button act upon another iframe with the script in parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

As stated above, how do I allow a button in the first iframe work in the next iframe when the script that possesses the function of the button is in the parent page?

this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Free Jokes!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var randomnumber;

            function window.iframes["left"].clickForJoke() {
                randomnumber=Math.floor( 1 + math.random() * 5);

                switch ( randomnumber ) {
                    case 1:
                        window.open( "joke1.html", target="left" );
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        window.open( "joke2.html", target="left" );
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        window.open( "joke3.html", target="left" );
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        window.open( "joke4.html", target="left" );
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        window.open( "joke5.html", target="left" );
                        break;

                    default:
                        window.open( "joke.html", target="left" );
                }
            }
  </script>
</head> 

<body>
    <iframe id="left" src="left.html" style="width:49.5%" style="height:100%"></iframe>

    <iframe id="right" src="right.html" style="width:49.5%" style="height:100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

If it's impossible to have this be done if the script is in the parent, I can simply move it to the left or right one.

Also how do I make the iframe go all the way down to the bottom of the screen. Apparently, I can only manipulate the width.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the buttons using:

```
document.frames['left'].document.getElementById('myButton')
```

Here's a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put that?

Comment: Where ever it is that you're trying to get a button to do something. You've got to identify the button first, check to see if it's been clicked and then do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: So if the button is on the right, and the place I'm trying to get it to access is on the left, I make a script, put that in it, and it should work?