# Changing the input in this form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, input

I'm working on a little project, and I would like some help on how to dynamically change the value of an input field on [this page](http://www.whec.com/article/12635/). It's the input under the "Which school has the most school spirit?" field.  For whatever reason, i'm having trouble just using javascript to identify the specified input element. I have'nt wrote javascript in awhile so I (hopefully) might just be missing something.

This is what I had (But it wasn't working):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("PDF_QT100")[0].children[0].value = "school"
```

Edit-

And this is the Error I recieve when I run the code on the page in Google Chrome's console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
```

Comment: Looks an awful lot like you are trying to rig this competition..

Comment: The input field is inside an iframe.

Comment: @Wezly, the winner was announced and we're now playing with it

Comment: This input is in a frame. You cannot access or update content due to security restrictions imposed by the browser.

Comment: You can't access elements inside an iframe unless the content is from the same domain as your parent page - [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)