# Encode image to Base64 from Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe which contains an image. The image source is linked to an image in an `S3` bucket. I need to encode this image in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and save the body of the iframe in the database.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get image data in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried, other than asking others to do your work for you, and why did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [How to access the <img /> in document from iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952985/how-to-access-the-img-in-document-from-iframe)

```
$('#Iframe1').contents().find('img').css({'width':'100%','height':'90%'});
```

and then use this function from here [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, but when i'm try to do this :  var image = $('#Iframe1').contents().find('img');               
 console.log("Base64" + current.getBase64Image(image));  I have error "The provided value is not a type of HTMLImageElement"

Comment: log out the value of image, tell me what it is

Answer (score 0):

if you store s3 bucket object in binary/blob,
e.g you have done on server something like:

```
...

//event.body - base64 received from client or REST
       
let decodedImage = Buffer.from(event.body.replace(/^data:(image|application)\/\w+;base64,/, ""), "base64")

        var params = {
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: key, // 
          Body: decodedImage,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64',
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: event.headers["Content-Type"],
        }


        // Uploading files to the bucket :
...
        s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
```

to received it and convert it back to base64 can be done on frontend with code (React hook in example):

```
const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      rs(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = rj
  })
}

function useImage({s3Link}) {
  const [src, setSrc] = React.useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function query({link}) {
      //link is link to s3 bucket URL link e.g
      // const link = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      //   Bucket: bucketnamw,
      //   Key: key,
      //   Expires: 30,
      // })

      const r = await fetch(link)
      const blob = await r.blob()
      const base64 = await blobToBase64(blob)
      console.log(`base64!`, base64)
      setSrc(base64)
    }

    if (s3Link) {
      query({link: s3Link})
    }
  }, [s3Link, setSrc])

  return [{src}]
}
```

...

```
const [hookImage] = useImage({s3Link})
```

view:

```
 {hookImage.src ? <img src={hookImage.src} /> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test image is "https://find-pets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/games/test.png".

If you want to get base64 from this url, use this function.

```
function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width =this.width;
        canvas.height =this.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        
        return dataURL;
    };

    img.src = url;
}
```

Call function as like this.

```
getBase64FromImageUrl("https://find-pets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/games/test.png");
```