# Chrome development tools - getElementsByClassName does not find element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to do some debugging using Chrome dev tools.  I'm looking at the HTML - and in the console trying to find the corresponding content using `documents.getElementsByClassName` - the call returns empty set - while I'm actually looking at the element.  I tried copy-pasting the class name - with the same result - see the screenshot below.  What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: The DOM tree you are looking at is probably in a frame... Check the frame selector dropdown in the toolbar...

Comment: @vishwanath Ah! that would explain it.  Just looked through the hierarchy - and the element in question is inside the iframe.  In this case, what's the right way to access it?

Comment: If you just want to check in the chrome developer console. There is selector of context <top frame> as seen in screenshot just above Console was cleared. Use that. If you need programmatically Id rather write answer for that.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: @vishwanath Yeah, I needed programmatically - but I got the answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe).  As for this question put your comment in an answer - and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting blank nodeList because you are looking at DOM tree in an iFrame. If you need to access nodes inside an iFrame, you first needs to get access to its window and DOM.

You can don that using following

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var innerWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
```

Once you have window and DOM you can just call the DOM related methods on document or if you have any other DOM parsing library like jQuery, object of which is stored on DOM. You can use that like following

Using document

```
innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('mh')
```

Using window

```
innerWindow.$('.mh')
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the `innerDoc` method is specific for native/vanilla Javascript, and the `innerWindow` method for jQuery? That they, i.e. the values of the two variables, are not interchangeable?

Comment: innerWindow is window object which contains all the global variables, jQuery being one. Whereas document object contains DOM API (yes its native) to access the DOM. PS: jQuery internally uses document object only.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand a couple of terms/rationales in your comment reply, probably due to not having had any formal JS training. But I'll rephrase the question: using vanilla JS, should I use the `innerDoc` method?

Answer (score -3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you must specify the index of the desired element.Example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];
```

Comment: Did you read the question/look at the screenshot?  I know it returns an array - but in my case it returns an empty array whereas the data is clearly there.

Comment: It actually returns a NodeList, not an array.