# why can't I get the content of another window?

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript beginner . I wrote a javascript code to open a website in new window and then get the content of that new window and display it in the first window .. and this is the code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newwin=window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
newwin.onload=function () 
{display.innerHTML = newwin.document.documentElement.innerHTML;};
</script>
</body></html>
```

It didn't work .. the web site opened in the new window but the content didn't appear in the first window .. why?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? Have two windows with same content?

Comment: Why don't you use an iframe?

Comment: You will have the same problem with an iframe unless the iframe is from the same domain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript

Comment: @bhspencer I know how Same-origin policy works. The point was using an iframe for showing another page. Of course you can't read the content of that page using JavaScript for security reasons. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: The OP is trying to access www.w3schools.com in there example. Presumable that is not in the same domain

Comment: If  [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header of another domain allows embedding of the page you can use an iframe. But you can't still use JavaScript for manipulating that page if some other options haven't been set.

Comment: Still, if OPs only purpose is to show w3schools somewhere on his page, why would not an `iframe` work? Where in the question do he say that he needs to access the document?

Comment: @Arg0n Yes, he can. But for using an iframe  there are some prerequisites that should exist. Modern browsers are more stricter that before. OP tries to read the `innerHTML` of another page's `document` element and that indicates that he wants to _access_ the document. Same-origian policy by default doesn't allow this.

Comment: @Vohuman Well, the only thing he does is copying the entire document into his page, leading to believe the only thing he want to do is show it.

Comment: @Arg0n That's true. That's why I have suggested using an iframe. What I wanted to say is he/she can't read/manipulate the contents of the embedded page by using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if the child window is from a different domain. Each domain is sandboxed from the others for security reasons.

Comment: if I use window.open, I can access it

Comment: Are you accessing a page on the same domain? In this example the OP is trying to access www.w3schools.com in the child window which presumably is in a different domain.

Comment: ouch, sorry, got it :). But should explain for more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use `_parent` as a second parameter to position your webpage. (BTW I am assuming you are allowing popups in your browser settings)

`var newwin=window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_parent");`

Comment: have you tried this. Does this work if the new window is not on the same domain as in the case in this example

Comment: @bhspencer I tried on my local machine before posting... FF + Chromium (using Ubuntu)

Comment: @bhspencer at my end the only thing browser ask for a confirmation to open, which I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors that prevent you:

1. Different domains
2. Even if same domain, you set onload function after calling window.open(). So the new "onload" behavior never runs

Solution for same domain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var w=window.open("another.html");
var tid = setInterval function () {
    if (w.document.readyState !== 'complete')
    return;
    clearInterval(tid);  
    display.innerHTML = w.document.documentElement.innerHTML);  
}, 100);
</script>
</body></html>
```