# How to query the embeded contents of an iframe to check for the presence of an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm curious if a javascript based script can search the embedded website's html and return a true/false value on the existence of ID #foo in its contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: I think you will find this answer useful :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

[.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) might be useful for you to read!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't this method fail when the iframed url is not on the same domain?