# Javascript getAttribute returns null for image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value of an image using this code:

image = doc.querySelector("img.product-pic-image").getAttribute("src");

I keep getting null.

Here is the DOM:

[image: DOM]

Please help. Here is the link of the product: 
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Aluminium-alloy-Pedal-for-Toyota-Mark-X-Reiz-AT-Stainless-Rubber-antiskid-Gas-accelerator-pedal-Brake/32571226955.html?spm=2114.13010208.99999999.261.YEDcC7

I am trying to access it from this page, once added to the cart:
http://shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/shopcart/shopcartDetail.htm?spm=2114.13010208.99999999.90000003

Thanks.

Comment: `document` not `doc`

Comment: Have you verified that `doc.querySelector("img.product-pic-image")` at least returns the image? I'm not sure what `doc` is, but did you mean `document`?

Comment: As stated by j08691 please make sure your using document.querySelector, not doc.querySelector.  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: The content of that page is sand boxed in an iframe, you won't be able to access it using the page's dom. document gives you access to the pages, dom, each iframe has their own encapsulated dom.

Comment: Yes. meant document....it doesn't return anythingl

Comment: You will have to use server side code to request the page contents and parse them server side. It can't be done client side.

Comment: @RonSimsII there is no way to access iframes?

Comment: @CarolKariuki see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo but I cant seem to find the iframes id as suggested in the link. Anything to use in place of id?

Comment: You can retrieve the iframe with  `document.querySelector` using something that match the iframe (not able to visit your link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet, it may help you:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("product-pic-image")[0].src;
```

Comment: It returns undefined... @hacketo

Comment: have you tried the edited question with index in the end:

Comment: it picks the image an index zero...I want to pick all the images...how to do this? @Godfather