# access widget's HTML element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, bootstrap-tour

There is a HTML widget loaded along with a webpage, when I do inspect element on it, the code shows as

[image: This is part of the widget's HTML document]

I need to access the widget's HTML elements in bootstrap tour for which I wrote following code (viewAll is the class name of one of the `<div>`):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('widgetIframe424615');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;


tour.addStep({lb}
element: innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("viewAll"),
placement: "right",
title: "My Cases Quick View",
content: tour.step1Content(),
template: tour.defaultTemplate({lb}currentStep: 1, totalSteps:totalStepsCount, closeButton: true{rb})
```

Here I'm trying to get the tour popover on element 'viewAll'.
The tour is working fine with the DOM elements loaded. But not working only for widget's elements.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access iframe elements in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: If you have any code to show us, please paste the code in here. Don't give us screenshots of code.