# accessing input field value inside an iframe form parent page javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, iframe

There are several posts on this, but no solution worked for me.
I have `parent.com` and iframe in that loading `child.com`

I want to access value of an input field which is inside in child.com (inside iframe)

here is what I tried so far

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.document.getElementById("input").value;

jQuery("#iframeID").contents().find('#input').val();

window.frames[0].getElementById("input").value;

jQuery('iframe[name=iframe]').contents().find('#input').val();
```

every attempt is resulting the same response

```
Blocked a frame with origin "parent.com" from accessing a frame with origin "child.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I dont how this worked for others and many accepted these answers.

Comment: Do you have control of both pages or only parent page? You can't access child page the way you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access iframe elements in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I dont think that this is a duplicate of that, I mentioned that the two domains are different.