# Access radio button value from iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a main-page with several separate iFrames including radio-buttons.
I want to validate the choices and because of that need the values of specific radio-button choices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>...</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#validate').click(function() {
alert('Value ' + $('#legitimation').contents().find('input[name="group_1"]').val());
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="legitimation" name="legitimation" src="Legitimation.html" width="300" height="800">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<input type="button" id='validate' name='validate' value='VALIDATE' />
</body>
</html>
```

inside my Legitimation.html i have several radio buttons (grouped up):

```
<form action="#" id="unique_id" class="productFilter">
    <fieldset id="step1" class="step1 option0">
        <legend>Legitimation</legend>
        <p>
            <input id="question_1" name="group_1" type="radio" value="1"/>
            <label for="question_1">Unidentifiziert</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="question_2" name="group_1" type="radio" value="2"/>
            <label for="question_2">Unlegitimiert</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="question_3" name="group_1" type="radio" value="3"/>
            <label for="question_3">Legitimiert</label>
        </p>
    </fieldset> [...]
```

I want to get feedback on which of the radio buttons was clicked, but i just can't seem to find a way on how to do that...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to do this? I'm having the same problem right now